# Select from database where a column equals any value in a variable

Tags: php, arrays, list

My database looks like this:

[image]

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
$following = "John, Sarah";
```

I would like to get the rows where the column 'username' is in the variable `$following` (in this case, John and Sarah). To do this, I had a look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356018/5798798 which suggested I use `IN` in my query, which I have attempted:

```
$following = "John, Sarah";
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE username IN ('$following')");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $row['eventtype'];
}
```

The problem is that the query is returning no data. My desired result would be:

> spoke walked

Comment: you didn't choose the `eventtype` column in the echo'd row, far as I can tell.

Comment: oh so that changed.

Comment: `echo $following = join("', '", $following);` - Tell me what that shows. I don't know how you're building your array, but that should be failing you here, being the single quotes.... *maybe*. @TheCodesee

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Actually I originally had a string... but now I realising I'm converting a string into an array to just turn it back into a string. The string is simply `John, Sarah` I'll edit my question

Comment: `$following = array("John", "Sarah");

echo $following = join(", ", $following);` this for me produced `John, Sarah` @TheCodesee should this be what you're looking for. But I may be wrong about it.

Comment: can you try this to see if this is what you're after? TBH, I haven't worked with arrays in years. `$following = "John, Sarah"; 
$following = explode(",", $following); 
$string = implode(", ", $following); 
echo $string;` @TheCodesee then use `$string` in the query; just an example here. Edit: might not add the quotes for each name in the query :(

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks, think I managed to do it by slightly modifying your answer to `$following = explode(", ", $following);
    $following = implode("','",$following);` Thank you!

Comment: @TheCodesee you're welcome. Funny that; I was thinking (doing similar) the same thing but just couldn't get that `implode()` to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @TheCodesee what would you like to do with the question? since there are other answers posted. I'm not for points (anymore, heh). Either you or I can post one to mark it off. If you want me to do it, I'll give kudos to you, or vice-versa. Either way is fine with me.

Comment: I take it you logged out then.

Comment: How is `$following` generated?  Is this coming from user supplied data? Or are you hardcoding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I suggested in comments to use the following:

```
$following = "John, Sarah"; 
$following = explode(", ", $following); 
$string = implode(", ", $following);
```

It ended up that I didn't include the quotes for the `implode()`'ing.

The final solution was to add the single quotes in the first parameter for the `implode()` function:

```
$following = implode("','",$following);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$following = join("', '", $following);
```

`join` no more returns an array. It is a string now.

---

You can use like [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in):

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($following ) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE username IN ($in)");
$stm->execute($following);
```

Comment: @TheCodesee if you use placeholders (`?`) as shown in the second example here, you'd need to either pass your array of values to `execute`, like `$stmt->execute($following);`, or bind the values individually before executing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah thought OP will find from the link. Updated!

Comment: @Thamilan Well, I was only guessing that that was why they said it didn't return anything. Who knows, though. :)

Answer (score -2):

with out using join you directly implode array by the following way

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE username IN ("'. implode('","', $following).'")');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $row['eventtype'];
}
```

Note: $following always should be in array

Comment: a missing single quote for the opening of this statement `'SELECT`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, thanks you, for pointing out mistake, I update the my answer